# Remove leading space from columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with `( 99| 100)` in the first cell(`A2`).

Using `=(split(A2," ( | ) ",true))` in cell `B2` I am getting `99` and using `=CONTINUE(A2, 1, 2)` i am getting `100` in cell `C2`.

There is a leading space in both `B2` and `C2` how do i remove it, i need to perform a few calculations on `B2` and `C2`.

I've tried using `trim` but it isn't working.

`=trim(split(B248," ( | ) ",true))`

For testing purposes i have the following code in cell `D2`  `value(B2)` and i get the error `Cannot parse text`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmZqKT8_r5b_dDJxSnh2Y09ndzhGWm10clp0TXpYT3c&usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to use the `REGEXREPLACE` function to get rid off the [white spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). It turns out that the [ASCII character 160](http://www.adamkoch.com/2009/07/25/white-space-and-character-160/) isn't considered to be a white space but a  “Non-breaking space”.

Therefore I used the `CODE` function to reveal the empty space (remove the open bracket first). For your particular setting, the following will work:

```
=SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B1,CHAR(160),""),"(|)")
```

Comment: Jacob, that works, but please could you explain what was I doing wrong there and how you went about it?

Comment: @debal See my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test and was able to get A2 and B2 to add without a problem.  Please see:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvRseCY0-3SVdEJybVU5U1pZYzdxX3NzNEVOekxFOVE&usp=sharing

Perhaps there is some column formatting on your values?

Comment: please check the sheet that i pasted

Comment: I just noticed that the space in your first example is actually a non-breaking space (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm), not a standard space (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm).

Comment: I tried several regex-based solutions and Jacob's is the best I've found.